# Dynamically generating Mocha tests from a large MongoDB collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mocha.js

In my Node.js project test suite I want to check every item in a MongoDB collection against a JSON schema. Using the [Mocha](https://mochajs.org/) test framework I can generate tests dynamically like so:

```js
describe('Lexemes', () => {
  // load schema validator
  var schema = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('public/schemas/lexeme.json'))
  var validate = ajv.compile(schema)

  it('receives data', async () => {
    // load all items in collection
    let items = await db.get('lexemes').find()
    items.forEach((item) => {
      // dynamically generated test for each result
      describe(item._id, () => {
        it('conforms to schema', () => {
          validate(item).should.be.true()
        })
      })
    })
  })
})
```

This works perfectly for smaller collections. However with one very large collection (4.5 million documents) I get a timeout:

```
Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
```

If I just increase the timeout to say 60s, I eventually get a **JavaScript heap out of memory** error. Clearly it's trying to put the whole collection in memory, which is not going to work.

I thought I would be able to use [Monk's result streaming](https://automattic.github.io/monk/docs/collection/find.html) like so:

```js
it('receives data', () => {
  return db.get('lexemes').find().each((item, { close, pause, resume }) => {
    describe(item._id, () => {
      it('conforms to schema', () => {
        validate(item).should.be.true()
      })
    })
  })
})
```

However this doesn't make any difference (note that I also tried returning a promise instead of using async/await, which didn't help either).

**Edit 1**

I tried manually paginating the data into smaller chunks using the limit/skip options to the Mongo query:

```js
const limit = 1000 // page size
var skip = 0
do {
  it(`receives data ${skip} to ${skip + limit - 1}`, async () => {
    let items = await db.get('lexemes').find({}, { limit: limit, skip: skip })
    items.forEach((item) => {
      describe(item._id, () => {
        it('conforms to schema', () => {
          validate(item).should.be.true()
        })
      })
    })
  })
  skip += limit
} while (skip < 5000000)
```

**Edit 2**

This avoids timeout errors and Mocha appears to be making progress with the "receives data x to y" tests, but when it starts executing the "conforms to schema" tests it throws the same out-of-memory error as above.

Any other ideas of what I could try?

Answer (score 0):

Well this doesn't solve the original problem, but I have had to settle for just testing a *sample* of the data from my large collection using MongoDB's [`$sample`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/) aggregation feature:

```js
const limit = 100000 // sample size
it(`receives data (${limit} samples)`, async () => {
  let items = await db.get('lexemes').aggregate([{ '$sample': { 'size': limit } }])
  items.forEach((item) => {
    describe(item._id}, () => {
      it('conforms to schema', () => {
        validate(item).should.be.true()
      })
    })
 })
})
```